# How to combine two dataframes and set one column based on the comparison of another column?

Tags: python, dataframe

```py
one = DataFrame({'a': ['apple', 'boy'], 'b': [4, 2]})
two = DataFrame({'a': ['cat', 'dog'], 'b': [5, 1]})
```

```py
>>> one
       a  b
0  apple  4
1    boy  2

>>>
>>>
>>> two
       a  b
0    cat  5
1    dog  1
```

And I want the combined dataframe (named as 'result') to be:

```
>>> result
       a  b
0    cat  5
1    boy  2
```

because 4 < 5 and result['a'][0] should be set as 'cat' instead of 'apple';
1 < 2 and result['a'][1] should be set as 'boy' instead of 'dog';

How to do that?

Comment: 2 is also smaller the 5 why is dog not cat?

Comment: i think he wants to compare row wise and `['boy', 2] > ['dog', 1]`

Comment: if one['b'][0] > two['b'][0]: result['a'][0]=one['a'][0] else the other. I think it goes something want he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
import numpy as np
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.where(one.b < two.b, two.a, one.a),
    'b': np.where(one.b < two.b, two.b, one.b)
})
print(result)
```

Output

```
     a  b
0  cat  5
1  boy  2
```

Comment: Sure, but what if the key is 'adams fine' instead of 'a' (with spaces)?

Comment: @Ron In that case, you can use the dictionary style of access like `one["adams fine"]`

Comment: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.

Comment: Is it because they are not of the same length?

Comment: @Ron For starters, please confirm if my post answers your question. Should you have a different question, update your question so that everyone can look at the real question instead of working through modifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
one = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['apple', 'boy'], 'b': [4, 2]})
two = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['cat', 'dog'], 'b': [5, 1]})
result = one.append(two)
result[(result['b']>1)].iloc[1:].sort_index()
```

output:

> > > result
> > > a  b
> > > 0    cat  5
> > > 1    boy  2

Comment: Seems the right result but the wrong process. Let's say change 1 into 0.1 and change 2 to 0.2 it's not working

Comment: I think it is better to update the question. It depend upon the task what exactly you want to do. if you change 0.1 then also change the conditional statement in pd.dataframe.